# Swift - Vidyo SDK problems in TestFlight releases

Tags: ios, swift, vidyo

I'm currently using Vidyo iOS SDK on Swift. 
Everything works great, except for the TestFlight releases of the app, that works different from local installations (directly from Xcode).

The problems come from the initialization of the ***VCConnector*** for custom handling of views, (***nil*** instead of ***UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&vidyoView)***).

```
connector = VCConnector(nil,
    viewStyle: .default,
    remoteParticipants: 10,
    logFileFilter: UnsafePointer("warning"),
    logFileName: UnsafePointer(""),
    userData: 0)
```

***The resulting version in TestFlight will not display the self camera*** (the preview of my video).

Has it occurred to someone?

Answer (score 1):

If you are uploading to TestFlight then it's likely a release build where speed optimization included **Speed [-O]**.
Try to switch onto default one (for release): Build Settings -> "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" -> Optimization level: No optimization **[-Onone]** OR Optimize for **Size [-Osize]**.